# @keyframes doesn't work with %

Tags: html, css, css-animations

The `.car1` moves only when using the `@keyframes`'s `from` & `to` but not when using `%`. Can anyone explain why is that so?

```css
.car1 {
  animation: car1 2s 2 forwards;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes car1 {
  from {transform: translateX(550px)}
  to {transform: translateX(-550px)}
}

.car2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  animation: car2 2s 2 forwards;
}

@keyframes car2 {
  0% {top: 30px}
  25% {top: 130px}
  40% {top: 230px}
  75% {top: 330px}
}
```

```html
<div class="car1">Car1</div>
<div class="car2">Car2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.car1 {
  animation: car1 2s 2 forwards;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes car1 {
  0% {transform: translateX(550px)}
  100% {transform: translateX(-550px)}
}

.car2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  animation: car2 2s 2 forwards;
}

@keyframes car2 {
  0% {top: 30px}
  25% {top: 130px}
  40% {top: 230px}
  75% {top: 330px}
}
```

```html
<div class="car1">Car1</div>
<div class="car2">Car2</div>
```

Hey just set from 0% and to 100% in @keyframes car1 it works fine!